# Using Attach API Outside Of JDK

Tags: api, compatibility, java

I have a small application that uses the Attach API to modify some third party classes during runtime. Alas, I have run into a large problem: the Attach API only comes with the JDK. The necessary files I can copy from the JDK and add into my project, but the library responsible for this(attach.(dll|so)) I can't. This is because I would have to copy attach.lib from a resource inside jar, and put it in the JRE/lib directory.

**An action that would not work if the user isn't root on a Linux machine, therefore losing compatibility to alot of users (as this app is supposed to run on a server, and most servers are Linux, and I can't be sure all are root)**

I looked into all the classes responsible for the attach API (VirtualMachine, AttachProvider etc) but found no place where it is loading the library.

Is it possible to do this? I mean, can I use the Attach API outside of a JDK installation? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by modifying `java.library.path`:

```
static void addToLibPath(String path) throws NoSuchFieldException,
                                             SecurityException,
                                             IllegalArgumentException,
                                             IllegalAccessException
{
    if (System.getProperty("java.library.path") != null) {
        // If java.library.path is not empty, we will prepend our path
        // Note that path.separator is ; on Windows and : on Unix-like,
        // so we can't hard code it.
        System.setProperty("java.library.path",
                           path + System.getProperty("path.separator")
                           + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    } else {
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);
    }

    // Important: java.library.path is cached
    // We will be using reflection to clear the cache
    Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
    fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
    fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
}
```

Call `addToLibPath("path")` will add `"path"` to `java.library.path`.

Please note that `java.library.path` is cached, and reflection is required to clear the cache.

Comment: I never would have thought the path is cached. I was wondering why it wasn't doing anything different on my changes... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to run the application looking to do the "attach" from within a JDK (not a JRE).  By doing this, you don't need to worry about providing the Attach API or its dependencies - as they are all provided for and managed by the JDK.  That said, you shouldn't have any "root" concerns with doing this - as you can extract and run/use a JDK as any user (it doesn't have to be installed / executed as "root").  That said, you'll just need to ensure that your program doing the attaching and the program being attached to are running as the same OS user as to not run into security restrictions.

Comment: Downloading, extracting and executing a JRE just for this is a bit overkill, in my opinion. My project is a lightweight (15KB) size plugin of a service, downloading an entire JDK would put alot of users off.

Comment: First, note that many applications require a JDK instead of just a JRE for similar reasons.  Otherwise, without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I'd try to figure out a way to meet your needs without using the attach API...  Maybe something like http://asm.ow2.org/ would also meet your needs?

Comment: I am using ASM. But I need to attach to the JVM and then use ASM to retransform the classes, and I can't without the Attach API :/

Comment: @Nox - why can't you have the JVM generate and load its own classes?  Why do you need to transform?  If libraries like Hibernate can do all of its bytecode manipulation without using attach, I highly doubt that your "lightweight project" needs to.  :-)

Comment: It does because as I said, it is a plugin. I wish to effectively "hack" the service that loaded it, but can't do so using the normal agent way because the service is loaded before my plugin for it.

Comment: Is this a plugin for a readily-available project that you're working with, that you could mention?  If you're constrained to its plugin-loading mechanisms, I'm probably out of ideas.  Otherwise, it would seem that it could be as simple as having the user modify the program's classpath to include a JAR of yours at the beginning - or having your plugin do this itself, even if it requires a one-time restart of the parent program.

Answer (score 0):

Our experience is that there is no reliable way to use the attach API without a full JDK. This was particularly acute on Windows. You might get it to work, but you might want to look into plain old JMX instead.